# How to stop divs from overlapping in safari

Tags: css, html

I have a table with text next to an image put in a flex row.

When I make the window narrower horizontally, the text goes "behind" the image, instead of wrapping and remaining contained by the div.

In chrome and mozilla all is fine, the problem comes only in Safari.

I tried with word-break, overflow-wrap, display block on the image but none helped.

This is my code: https://codepen.io/matteocarpi/pen/dwzjrb?editors=1100

```css
    .show-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      // margin-bottom: 3rem;
    }
    .expectations {
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 0.5em;
      vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    .statement {
      vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    .offer {
      padding-left: 0.5em;
    }
    .table-wrap {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      padding: 0 2em;
    }
    .offer {
      margin-top: 3rem;
      margin-left: 2rem;
    }
    td {
      vertical-align: baseline;
      // min-width: 540px;
    }
    tr {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    td > p {
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: 400;
      margin: 0.4rem 0;
      word-break: break-all;
      hyphens: auto;
    }
    
    .img-show-wrap {
      display: block;
    }
    .img-show{
      margin-top: -3rem;
      margin-right: 3rem;
      width: 30rem;
      border: solid 3px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="show-wrapper">
      <div class="table-wrap">
        <div>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="expectations"><h1> {{ page.expectation_title_en 
    }} </h1></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="expectations"><p class="statement">{{ page.expectation_1_en | markdownify }}</p></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="expectations"><p class="statement">{{ page.expectation_2_en | markdownify }}</p></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="expectations"><p>{{ page.expectation_3_en | markdownify }}</p></td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>

    <div>
      <table class="offer">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="statement"><h1>{{ page.offer_title_en }}</h1></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="statement"><p>{{ page.offer_1_en | markdownify }}</p></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="statement"><p >{{ page.offer_2_en | markdownify }}</p></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="statement"><p >{{ page.offer_3_en | markdownify }}</p></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="img-show-wrap">
      <img class="img-show" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

this is the actual page: https://matteocarpi.github.io/crdc/en/the-show

I would like the text to wrap and to never overlap with the image (as it works well on codepen's snippet, but not on the actual page in safari)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Matteo

Comment: Note: your codepen demo is empty ...

Comment: Try `style="word-break:break-word;"` in the text cells of your table

Comment: Thanks @DavidDeprost, I changed it now it should be online

Comment: @Smitty-Werben-Jager-Manjenson, thanks for the comment, no luck with that

Comment: do you really need the tables?

Comment: I thought i did, maybe I don’t? Do you think it will solve the problem to take them out? I’ll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DaFois commented, it was enough to remove the table layout and use loose paragraphs in flexbox.

Here the new code:

```css
.show-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.expect-offer-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.expectation {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}
.offer {
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="show-wrapper">

  <div class="expect-offer-wrap">

    <div class="expectation">
      <h1> {{ page.expectation_title_en }} </h1>

      <p>{{ page.expectation_1_en | markdownify }}</p>

      <p>{{ page.expectation_2_en | markdownify }}</p>

      <p>{{ page.expectation_3_en | markdownify }}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="offer">
      <h1>{{ page.offer_title_en }}</h1>

      <p>{{ page.offer_1_en | markdownify }}</p>

      <p >{{ page.offer_2_en | markdownify }}</p>

      <p >{{ page.offer_3_en | markdownify }}</p>
    </div>

  </div>


    <div class="img-show-wrap">
      <img class="img-show" src="{{ page.image | relative_url }}" alt="">
    </div></div>

</div>
```

Thanks!